# How do I validate XHTML, ATOM, and CSS in Ruby?

Tags: css, xml, ruby, validation

I'd like to run validations on the static web content I'm creating.  Are there any good validators for XHTML, ATOM, and CSS?  (The first two would be covered by any general-purpose XML-DTD validator.)

**Later**

I failed to specify that I wanted *local* validation, not something that uses the W3C service.

Comment: A shameless plug, and there are a few of these around, but I wrote a little markup validator gem which uses the w3c api you can see it here http://github.com/DylanFM/please_validate/tree/master

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nokogiri ( http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/tree/master ) is great tool for parsing XML/XHTML/HTML/etc and it looks like it can validate as well:

```
Nokogiri::XML.parse(string_or_io, nil, nil, Nokogiri::XML::PARSE_DTDVALID)
```

At the moment, I don't believe that you'll find a pure ruby project that will validate your CSS directives, but there are many that will let you use ruby code to generate valid CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Check [W3C Validators Ruby Gem](http://code.dunae.ca/w3c_validators/).

> W3C Validators is a Ruby wrapper for
>   the World Wide Web Consortium's online
>   validation services.
>
> It supports the markup validator, the
>   feed validator and the CSS validator.

Otherwise, [W3C's Validator has a SOAP API](http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html) which you can use even from Ruby, or there is an article demonstrates how to [validate HTML in Ruby with 
libxml](http://overstimulate.com/articles/valid-wellformed-html-libxml-ruby-rails).

Answer (score 1):

Just as an info: Nokogiri 1.3.0 was released today and now has validation classes for XML inside the official release. No need to get the trunk version.

http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/

Comment: gem install nokogiri will get you the latest release, not a 'trunk' version, which would be master on git.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to validate the markup on all of our pages through our test suite:
[assert_valid_markup](http://github.com/wr0ngway/assert_valid_markup/)

It provides nice markup testing like:

```
class FooControllerTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_bar_markup
    get :bar
    assert_valid_markup
  end
end
```

or

```
class FooControllerTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_bar_markup
    assert_valid_markup "<div>Hello, world.</div>"
  end
end

# For the ultimate in convenience, use the class-level method to validate a slew of
# actions in one line. Par exemple:

class FooControllerTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  assert_valid_markup :bar, :baz, :qux
end
```

Comment: did you delete that repository? GitHub says it doesn't exist

Comment: Hm, maybe it's a GitHub problem. The link doesn't work, but the URL does.

Comment: I fixed the link.  Just had to get rid of the /tree/master bit.

Answer (score 0):

[Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/), by w3c, can validate XHTML.

There are also a [CSS Validation Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) and a [Feed Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/feed/).

Is that what you were looking for?

If you want to validate from inside a ruby program, [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2008/04/02/xhtml-validation-script-using-ruby.aspx) is an article explaining how to do that using this services. I didn't try it, sorry.

Comment: Going from the question title I'd say (s)he's looking for a Ruby script that can perform the validation locally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but...  For local validation for HTML-- you could take a look at my html_validation gem. It wraps HTML Tidy which is put out by the W3c.  It comes with an RSpec matcher.

https://github.com/ericbeland/html_validation